# Pulling in external HTML content into an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, httprequest, httpresponse

I have been able to successfully pull in content using HTTPGET, but I only see the AMPScript when I view in Email Overlay view (under tracking reports)

```
%%[ 

var @getStatus, @getURL, @content 
set @getURL = "http://www.example.com"
set @content = HttpGET(@getURL, false, 2, @getStatus)
set @content = Replace(@content,'href="http','href="httpgetwrap|http') 

]%%
%%=TreatAsContent(@content)=%%%
```

Is there another function/method I should be using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. That's the way to do it.

Content is generally stored with AMPScript intact, not rendered.  The _Job and _Click [System Data Views](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) do contain some rendered dynamic content, but that's the only place I can recall that occurring.

If you're looking to archive rendered emails, it generally takes the form of CC/BCC or ponying up for an engagement for archiving sends in FTP. Financial institutions need to do this sometimes.

Our team has tried to retrieve and re-create rendered emails via scripting and/or API several times only to find it too troublesome.